# Deserialization of a property typed as object results XmlNode array

Tags: c#, deserialization

i have the following XML file to deserialize:

```
<RoutesConfiguration>
    <RouteList>
        <SpecialRoute Name="Url" Urlpattern="MyUrl">
            <Defaults>
                <Item>
                    <Key>controller</Key>
                    <Value>Rss</Value>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <Key>action</Key>
                    <Value>LastItems</Value>
                </Item>
                 <Item>
                    <Key>id</Key>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                </Item>
            </Defaults>
        </SpecialRoute>
    </RouteList>
</RoutesConfiguration>
```

This is my deserialization code:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RoutesConfigurationPath"]));
 var routes = (RoutesConfiguration)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

This class represents **every "Item"** Element in my XML file.

```
public class Item
{
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Im getting my deserialized instance okay, but with one issue on the property "Value" of every Item.

This "value" propery is being deserialized as **System.Xml.XmlNode[]**. The thing is that i cannot type this property to string, or int since this value can be set to both types. For this reason i typed as "Object".

Do you know any way to get from deserialization the right type and not this XmlNode array?

Thanks

Regards.

Jose

Comment: Where did you get this xml file, which you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: Why don't you deserialize it into `string` first and than you can try `int.TryParse` to find out if it is `string` or `int`?